# binary object file changing in each build

Tags: c++, g++

When compiling using G++ GNU compiler every time I do a build, without changing source code I get a different binary object file. Is there a compile option that will give me the same binary each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deterministic binary output with g++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653874/deterministic-binary-output-with-g)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Copied from the GCC man-page:

> -frandom-seed=string
>   This option provides a seed that GCC uses when it would otherwise
>   use random numbers.  It is
>   used to generate certain symbol names that have to be different
>   in every compiled file.  It
>   is also used to place unique stamps in coverage data files
>   and the object files that produce
>   them.  You can use the -frandom-seed option to produce reproducibly identical object files.
>
> The string should be different for every file you compile.

Answer (score 0):

You should better use [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile). This way if your source didn't change, the compilation will be skipped, so the object files won't be changed.

Edit: after some thinking, it's possible to address your comment with the makefile which separates preprocessing and actual compilation. and some dirty tricks.

Example makefile:

```
all: source

source: source.i.cpp
    @cmp -s source.i.cpp source.i.prev || g++ source.i.cpp -o source
    @touch source
    @cp source.i.cpp source.i.prev

source.i.cpp: source.cpp
    @g++ -E source.cpp >source.i.cpp
```

Please note the the executable's **time** is changed, but the contents not (if you changed only the comments, not the actual code).

Comment: I am changing source but only adding comments not changing the program. Do you have a solution for this case?

Comment: Actually no, changing source file means recompilation :-( Make and other build tools are not so clever to understand that only the comments are changed.

Comment: Extended the answer to cover your case :)

Comment: I get your point, but I think the poster wants *build reproducibility*.  Often, it doesn't normally matter that a compiler produces binary equivalent data.  Some code sequences are logically equivalent.  A compiler can pick one on Sunday and a different one on Monday; a randomly directed optimizer may do this, for instance searching a set of equivalence sequence based on optimal run time.  The permutations of equivalent basic blocks can be huge.  There is nothing to say a compiler must produce the same output.  That is just a nice thing that a particular compiler **may** guarantee.

Comment: @artless noise: here is [an article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/05/31/past-performance-is-no-guarantee-of-future-results.aspx) on a connected issue. In principle, you are right, a compiler is not obliged to guarantee that the same source code produces the same compiled code, and actually needs to do some additional work to ensure that.