# Trying deterministic gcc compilation, symbol table problems

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, elf, symbol-table

I work for embedded systems and I am trying to make a build that yields exactly the same executable each time. Using -frandom-seed certainly helped to stabilize names that were otherwise variable, but still I have a couple of symbols that I have problems with. For example:

0x00003bfc                _ZN13WorkingMemory17ReadTransactionalERN3HSL4FileERN58_GLOBAL__N_..*..*.._.._working_memory.cc_AE42A16A_FF4623503AllE

The ".._.." etc. part was evidently worked out of what I passed as -frandom-seed, id est, the source filename. Of the couple of hex number that follows sometimes, the second one sometimes is different, and I guess it is probably linked to the compilation date, but I am not sure.
I am working on ARM, using gcc 3.4.0, using FLAT executables. I tried to remove symbols using strip on the ELF file, but that prevents FLAT conversion.
Any ideas?

Comment: Generic how to version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653874/deterministic-binary-output-with-g

Comment: Give us a *precise* input (program), setup (distro, GCC version, etc.) and compilation commands that allows us to reproduce you. Then it will be much easier to help.