# Why do builds with identical settings on the same machine/environment result in slightly different binary files?

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, compilation

I've noticed that if I compile binaries back to back  on the machine/env with identical settings, the resulting binaries will have different MD5/SHA1 signatures, even if they are the exact same size.

I was wondering if anyone knew why that would be? Should the compiler not  have identical results with identical inputs?

I've noticed this both on Linux and in Visual Studio.

Comment: The most common explanation is that certain header fields can contain time stamps for when the binary was built.

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely make sense. I guess one could verify this theory by compiling a hello world cpp program with no header files to see if the outputted binary is the same

Comment: Actually, I was referring to the binary header that all executables have. Check out e.g. the Portable Executable specification for the Microsoft platforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to produce deterministic binary output with g++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653874/how-to-produce-deterministic-binary-output-with-g)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError This should be an answer.