# gcc-arm Compiler produce different object file for the same source file

Tags: c, gcc, arm, compiler-optimization, eabi

Using the GCC compiler for ARM (windows) :

> *arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2012.09-63) 4.7.2* version

I have got different object file produced every ~5 times i compiled the same source file.

The optimization level 3 (aggressive) is used, compiler options used:

> -O3 -mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -fshort-wchar -fshort-enums  -funsafe-math-optimizations -mvectorize-with-neon-quad

The dump of the different object files (using objdump) shows too many differences in assembly instructions , registers and addresses used.

- Is it normal that compiler optimize/compile exactly the same source
  file differently and produce different object files ?! is it a compiler bug ?
- How to avoid this behavior without turning off aggressive
  optimization ?

EDIT:
object files differences snippet:

object_file_dump_A:

```
0000350 <PreInit>:
 350:   e3003000    movw    r3, #0
 354:   e3403000    movt    r3, #0
 358:   e92d4ff0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, lr}
 35c:   e1a09000    mov r9, r0
 360:   e24dd034    sub sp, sp, #52 ; 0x34
 /*some identical ASM for both files */
 388:   e1a0700b    mov r7, fp
 38c:   e1a0600b    mov r6, fp
 390:   e300a000    movw    sl, #0
 394:   e340a000    movt    sl, #0
 398:   e5911004    ldr r1, [r1, #4]
 39c:   e8ae0003    stmia   lr!, {r0, r1}
```

object_file_dump_B:

```
00000350 <PreInit>:
 350:   e3003000    movw    r3, #0
 354:   e3403000    movt    r3, #0
 358:   e92d4ff0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, lr}
 35c:   e1a08000    mov r8, r0
 360:   e24dd034    sub sp, sp, #52 ; 0x34
  /*some identical ASM for both files */
 388:   e1a0700b    mov r7, fp
 38c:   e3009000    movw    r9, #0
 390:   e3409000    movt    r9, #0
 394:   e5911004    ldr r1, [r1, #4]
 398:   e8ae0003    stmia   lr!, {r0, r1}
 39c:   e5b30010    ldr r0, [r3, #16]!
```

EDIT:

source code :

```
void PreInit(init_T *f_params, results_T *results) 
{
  u8 i, j, k, idx;
  const u8 cr_index[4] = {0, 1, 2, 7};
  const u8 minVal[] = {2, 4, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19}; 
  const u8 maxVal[] = {0, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18}; 

  memset(f_params, 0, sizeof(init_T));

  _ASSERT(CONF_NUM_X_LIMITS == CST_NbSLi);
  _ASSERT(CONF_NUM_CRITERIA == CST_NbIdxCriteria);

  for (i = 0; i < CST_NbSLi; ++i)
  {
    f_params->_sli[i].x = s_limits[i];
    for (j = 0; j < CST_NbIdxCriteria; ++j)
    {
      f_params->_sli[i].criteria[j] = conf_criterias[i][j];
    }
  }
/*some code*/
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the code is not including some header file that is being regenerated on each build?

Comment: @jxh: yes am sure ! there is now regenerated headers included

Comment: You can try to compile with `-E`, and see if there's a difference. In case there is, comparing will be much easier than comparing machine code.

Comment: How about source control variables? Do you use something like `$Id:` or `$Revision:` in your source or header files?

Comment: @jxh: No, please note that i am building same files at the same machine repetitively by running the build batch ( i wrote ) many times ! aside notes: cmake is used for build. JOM is used instead of nmake.

Comment: @ugoren : tried and the preprocessed files are always same.

Comment: Try using objdump to see what really is different. try objdump -d to see if code is different, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [object file changing in each build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140329/binary-object-file-changing-in-each-build).  This is not a compiler bug.  The compiler must give the same answer for the same input; often there are multiple assembler sequences that are equivalent.   The simplest source `char myData = __DATE__ __TIME__;` will change with every compile.

Comment: Can you show some examples of the different code sequences?

Comment: @artlessnoise: interesting , i will give it a try but it is not clear for me how the compiler depends on a seed !

Comment: @unixsmurf: snippet of objdump of two files added above !

Comment: @Abdurahman: There is something seriously fishy going on here. Why is the compiler using movw/movt to load #0 into a register, which can be done by a single instruction? And why is the link register used as a base register for a store-multiple? Can you show us the source of PreInitFuna?

Comment: @unixsmurf: [check this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjagdjbf.html) and [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihcfbhg.html) seems to be normal

Comment: The assembler code is equivalent.  Some algorithms are heuristic; often the same code is approximately the same run time if the memory access pattern is the same.  It doesn't matter which register is used on the ARM as they are *symmetric*.  So whether it is `mov r9, r0` or `mov r8, r0` if `r9`/`r8` are treated the same in both *object* files, the same thing happens.  A heuristic maybe guided by a random value.

Comment: The `movw/movt` are senseless with zero.  It make sense if you are loading from another register or non-zero constant in both parts.  The `movw/movt` have a purpose; **unixsmurf** is just pointing out that a *peephole* type of optimization should have made them one instruction.

Comment: @Abdurahman: There is nothing wrong with it, but the value #0 can be loaded through a single instruction, so it wouldn't make sense for the compiler to use two. It doesn't for me when I build a simple test with the flags you're using, but then I'm not using your toolchain version. ...unless of course that is an inline data relocation... Again, the source code would be useful, in order to be able to do more than guess.

Comment: @unixsmurf: got it,so single mov instruction would be sufficient, however this wired usage of 'movw/movt' is present in the two object files. question updated with source code

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others the assembly codes are equivalent. 
If you look at them closely, the command

e1a0600b    mov r6, fp

It moves fp to r6, but the r6 register is not used later. 
So, if we consider the randomization tactics to allocate registers, and code creation, the variations are not big and in the second part the optimization removed the line.

Comment: so how to stop that ? provided solution there didn't work :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140329/binary-object-file-changing-in-each-build